# Why is a logarithmic function one to one? (and exponential function).

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

$f(x)=\log_a{x}$. This is a logarithmic function. I don't know but I think that it's easier to understand this function if you put it this way, $a^{f(x)}=x$. So one of my questions is that if $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$ then $x_1 \neq x_2$, which probably is the same as asking why is the exponential function one to one, and I also wanted to ask why it is an increasing function? And my other question is that if $0<c<1$ (for example) and $b \ge 1$, why is $b^c$ more than one?

Comment: Construction of logarithmic and exponential functions requires a bit of analysis and knowledge about series. I'm assuming that you have not yet reached to that level in maths. So for elementary proofs, you can just assume that log and exp are inverses of each other and use its properties to show that it is indeed 1-1. It is clear geometrically as well. Same goes for showing that it is an increasing function.

Comment: I really don´t know about that but it that doesn´t matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all they are not one to one on the complex numbers.  But that's a different issue.  They are as far as real analysis is concerned.

Now if $b>1$ then $b*b>b*1=b>1>\frac 1b>...$.  So inductively  $b^n $ is increase on the integers.

(If $0 <b <1$ the $b^n $ is decreasing but all arguments and results are equivalent.)

We can extend that to to rationals by noting that $\frac am <\frac cd$ (wolog for positive values) means $ad <mc $ and so $b^{am}=\sqrt [m]{b^a}=\sqrt[mc]{b^{ac}}< \sqrt[ad]{b^{ac}}=\sqrt[d]{b^c}=b^{\frac cd} $.

And for the reals... that depends on how you defined $b^x $ but it is clearly increasing either by limits or by the nature of integrals of positive values (integrals of positive values obviously increase over larger range.)

So $b^x $ increasing.

And increasing function *must* be 1-1, mustn't they?  Think about it.  If $x\ne y $ then either $x <y$ or $y <x $.  That means $f (x)<f (y)$ or $f (y)<f (x) $.

So $b^x $ is 1-1.

So $\log_b x $ is 1-1 as $b^k=x\iff \log_b x=k $.  So if $\log_b x=\log_b y=k $ then $b^k=y $ and $b^k=x $.  So $x=y$.